# Create separate line for specific use

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to create separate line and and I do it with the Use of HR tag

The problem is that I want it to apply to specific line and not for all the line,
how can I do this?

```
hr {
    border: #333333;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate and attach any screenshot or demo, will be helpful for us to answer..

Comment: Cannot you use a custom class?

Comment: @Thauwa-can you show how ?

Comment: @shopiaT : is the demo helps you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

HTML:

```
<div>abc</div>
<hr class="red" />
<div>def</div>
<hr />
<div>ghi</div>
```

CSS:

```
.red{
    border:1px solid red;
}
hr{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xa6sU/)

Answer (score 1):

You can give some id to the specific he that you want to change.
For example:

```
  <style>
    #name{

    width:100px

    }
  </style>


    <hr id="name">
```